# Remove Array Controller observer

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Observer added for array controllers are not removed.
Code for adding :

```
[self.arrayController addObserver:self
                       forKeyPath:@"selectionIndexes"
                          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                          context:nil];
```

Code to remove observer :

```
@try {
    //[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectionIndexes"];
    [self.arrayController removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectionIndexes"];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {}
```

Even after removing observers its not effective, and `observeValueForKeyPath` is getting invoked. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have added multiple observers.
Try setting a breakpoint at your addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context line and see if it is being called more than the removeObserver:forKeyPath line.

Comment: That s not possible because I have wrapped these remove/add observers in another class methods, so before adding there is a call to `[self removeObservers]` to ensure any previous added observer is removed. Still checked again to check if its added more times than being removed, but its not, there are 2 calls to add and remove. But still it gets called twice.

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the number to a single call? It might help identify where the issue is.

Comment: I need to remove observer do something in the back and turn on observer again. But now it keeps on adding observers every time. Every thing works fine, until I remove and add. So the problem is, its not getting removed.

Comment: Perhaps an alternative is to add and remove the observer once.
Then, add a BOOL that allows you to bypass the contents of the observeValueForKeyPath instead. The observeValueForKeyPath is always called, but an if statement testing your BOOL will determine if your code is run or not.